# Creating a data data frame from a list of values while keeping spaces

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to create a data frame based on a text file but it is a little tricky because I need to keep the spaces in specific areas.

I am using this generic script to import the text file line by line so I can keep the spacing as is

```
conn <- file(path,open="r")
lines <- readLines(conn)
for (i in 1:length(lines)){
print(lines[i])
}
close(conn)
```

The output of the text file when printed in rstudio looks like this:

```
2000000023809930294763           42500091-003       7659818    790000020133D060P      T
```

I would like to convert this over to a data frame that looks like this but the spaces have to be included and counted as characters.

```
           col1          |              col2     |         col3  |
   2000000023809930294763|           42500091-009|        7659818|
```

I have been unable to do this using the traditional as.data.frame() function as it eliminates the spaces.

Comment: Does `read.csv('your_file.txt', header = T, sep = ";", colClasses = 'character')` work for you? You might wanna replace the sep-argument, but I'm not sure how your file is delimited..

Comment: Well dont Majo! it worked. however oddly enough, when I print it in the console it looks perfect but when I open the dataframe itself, the spaces do not exist.

Comment: @YaRrrrrMatey: The RStudio viewer trims them for display, but they do exist.